# blender particle animation export fbx

Tags: animation, particles, .fbx

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AhsZ5Ykm63c

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3EQ3WfHF_Qo&list=LL&index=2

I think to extract particle animation to fbx extension, I think I need to convert it to mesh first, but I tried both methods above, but I couldn't convert the particle to mesh.
Please help me

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.